# could not convert from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to map

Tags: c++, c++11

my code is as bellow:

```
class A{
private:
    size_t linearProbing(T k, size_t i);

    size_t quadraticProbing(T k, size_t i);

    size_t doubleHashing(T k, size_t i);

    std::map<std::string, size_t (*)(T, size_t)> probeFunctionMap = {
            {"linearProbing",    this->linearProbing},
            {"quadraticProbing", this->quadraticProbing},
            {"doubleHashing",    this->doubleHashing}
    };
}
```

And the error is:

> error: could not convert '{{"linearProbing", ((HashTableOpeningAddress<int>*)this)->HashTableOpeningAddress<int>::linearProbing}, {"quadraticProbing", ((HashTableOpeningAddress<int>*)this)->HashTableOpeningAddress<int>::quadraticProbing}, {"doubleHashing", ((HashTableOpeningAddress<int>*)this)->HashTableOpeningAddress<int>::doubleHashing}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int (*)(int, long unsigned int), std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int (*)(int, long unsigned int)> > >'

I guess the method I used to init the map is wrong, but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: A function pointer cannot capture state (like `this`). Use std::function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function pointer cannot store the state that you care about (aka `this`). You need to be able to store this state so that you can call using `this` later when you use this map. An example might be:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<size_t(T, size_t)>>
```

The `std::function` will let you store the state. But you cannot create a std::function with `this->function_name`. That is close to *calling* the function. So you have 2 options:

- `std::bind` - hard
- `lambda` - easy

So lets look at a lambda. An example would be:

```
[this](T k, size_t i) { return functor(k, i); }
  ^ Capture our state, aka `this`
           ^ take the same arguments as the function we care about
                                 ^ Call the function we care about
```

We can set up a bunch of these lambdas (using a macro for ease):

```
 #define AS_FUNCTOR(functor) [this](T k, size_t i) { return functor(k, i); }

    std::map<std::string, std::function<size_t(T, size_t)>> probeFunctionMap = {
            {"linearProbing",    AS_FUNCTOR(linearProbing)},
            {"quadraticProbing", AS_FUNCTOR(quadraticProbing)},
            {"doubleHashing",    AS_FUNCTOR(doubleHashing)}
```

This will make a map that we can use! [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccfd4f37f8a90b43).

Comment: Thank you very much! My problem has been solved.

Comment: @JiangZiyang good to hear. Please tick the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C-style and C++ member function pointers.
You have to explicitly qualify `A::` everything.

```cpp
    typedef size_t (A::*ProbeFn)(T, size_t);

    size_t linearProbing(T k, size_t i);
    size_t quadraticProbing(T k, size_t i);
    size_t doubleHashing(T k, size_t i);

    std::map<std::string, ProbeFn> probeFunctionMap = {
            {"linearProbing",    &A::linearProbing},
            {"quadraticProbing", &A::quadraticProbing},
            {"doubleHashing",    &A::doubleHashing}
    };
```

Then to call:

```cpp
    size_t useit( const std::string& fname, T t, size_t value ) {
        ProbeFn fn = probeFunctionMap[fname];
        return (*this.*fn)(t,value);
    }
```

or

```
 return (this->*fn)(t,value);
```